# name forgeign key in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I am using the Hibernate Tools ant task to generate DDL from JPA annotated entities. With hibernate annotations you can name the foreign key using

```
@JoinColumn(name = "foo")
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "fk_foo")
```

Is there a pure JPA way of achiving the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. JDO is the only persistence specification allowing definition of FK names, onUpdate/onDelete actions etc. JPA (even in JPA2) simply doesn't go there.

--Andy ([DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org))

Answer (score 1):

Not in annotation. You can however set the [columnDefinition](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#columnDefinition()) and write the foreign key in there.

Comment: Worth noting that not all RDBMS accept names of the "FK" in the CREATE TABLE statement under column/constraint definition, and also that since this JPA text component is undefined  in terms of its content, you cannot rely on the result from different JPA implementations

Comment: Depend on your implementation and target database, it can be useful. Personally I think that it should be defined in the JPA standard, but I try to be pragmatic and play with the cards I have...